# MUI v5 - Add component name to `styled` class names?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I did some search in github and here, but maybe I'm doing it the wrong way.

Using `styled` from `@mui/material/styles` generates random class names like this:

[image]

```js
const TitleWrapper = styled('div')`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
`
```

Sometimes it becomes hard to debug the app when we don't know where the rendered component came from.

There's an `option` parameter that can be passed to `styled` with a `label` prop that adds a suffix to the class:

[image]

```js
const TitleWrapper = styled('div', { label: 'TitleWrapper' })`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
`
```

Is there an automated way of adding that suffix to identify the component? It's really painful to do this in every single component.

Comment: I have the same problem, wondering if there is a way to sett "autoLabel" or something in a config file, like it is for @emotion. Did you find any solution? @

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/17430352/luiz-felipe-felicio

Comment: No solution found @KimVu

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet @vbotio, actually I moved to another project that does not use this kind of custom component a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to update my `babel.config.js` file with the following changes

```
plugins: [
  [
    '@emotion',
    {
      autoLabel: 'always',
      importMap: {
        '@mui/material': {
          styled: {
            canonicalImport: ['@emotion/styled', 'default'],
            styledBaseImport: ['@mui/material', 'styled'],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
],
```

I hope this is useful to someone who faces the same issue.

Comment: This seems to be a great solution for those who don't use CRA or who tweaks it's config with libs like craco. I forgot to mention that I'm using CRA.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a custom class name i would like to suggest you to use scss (your own custom classes and styles), then you can put every style you need there , actually that's what i am doing right now, except when i need some styles based on some dynamic data then i can use both: my custom scss classes and styled-component class

Comment: I would like to achieve a more "native" solution.